# Will I lose my escape pod if I use it?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've now got a ship and it's TOTALLY AWESOME, ahem.

It's got an escape pod that I can interact with. For some reason I'm not sure why you can interact with it, what it does or why it's intractable.

If I use it, will it jetison me? Or will I lose the pod? Usually, I'd stick a quicksave, hit it and see, but with the MMO aspect, I can't save to see what it does.

Anyone tried using it yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I try to use my escape pod, an error message shows, saying “The escape pod is unavailable at this time.”

My guess is that it's either for some mission, where you will have to use it, or it serves no purpose at all (for now?).

Answer (score 2):

It's for other people to get off your ship.  For example, if you did a mission with a friend on board and they then want to do a different mission they can use the pod to leave your ship without you having to dock somewhere first.  I have heard that when someone used it himself in his own ship he then had to redo the mission where he gets his craft again, so if you use it there's a chance that you'll lose your ship and have to redo the mission to retrieve it again, so don't use your own pod!

Comment: I've tried it and as above, you just get a message telling you it's not available, you don't lose your ship. Although that's when you are solo in your ship. Perhaps the bug is if your team leave by the pod and you do also, you lose your ship?

Comment: Doig the quest where you get your ship again doesn't make any sense, because it's tied to the plot (e.g. it would mean you get the ship from a character that wouldn't be able to do it now).